# Pivot table with double rows or going from wide to long in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

How can I go from wide to long in Google Sheets based on two different columns or create a pivot table where I specify two different columns from the original matrix as rows?

Please see [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/165od08iXSbNfAFZAaOQuLWZuW51WUYev4g6ArzbptnE/edit?usp=sharing) for intended effect:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple approach. I don't think you can use a pivot table because the values have to be summaries of a numeric value, or at least counts, not a string value.

To get the times:

```
=transpose(C2:C)
```

To get the lecturers (fairly big assumption that there are no lecturers that work only as assistants but this can be changed later):

```
=unique(B:B)
```

If there are additional lecturers working only as assistants:

```
=unique({B:B;D2:D})
```

Then to get the topic corresponding to a particular lecturer or assistant:

```
 =ArrayFormula(IFERROR(vlookup(filter(F2:F,F2:F<>"")&filter(G1:1,G1:1<>""),{B2:B&C2:C,A2:A},2,false))&
    IFERROR(vlookup(filter(F2:F,F2:F<>"")&filter(G1:1,G1:1<>""),{D2:D&C2:C,A2:A},2,false)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks-- You can use pivot tables with text using join and custom function, however in this instance with two different columns you need to do a "double" pivot which cannot be done AFAIK. I found the [reshape](https://github.com/rgertenbach/Reshape) package allowing similar wide-long and long-conversions similar to the reshape package in R.

Comment: That's interesting. Also I think my answer is fine if you can only have one topic for a particular lecturer (or assistant) and time combination as in your test data, but would have to do it differently if you wanted to list all topics for a particular lecturer-time combination. Probably then just filter topics by lecturer and time and concatenate.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this all in one go:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({
 A1:B,       TEXT(C1:C, "hh:mm"); 
 A2:A, D2:D, TEXT(C2:C, "hh:mm")}, 
 "select Col2,max(Col1) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2 
  pivot Col3", 1))
```

[image: 0]